# JavaScript, not printing

Tags: javascript

I am working on a function that does a basic loan amortization that worked when I used a "prompt" to get the input. Going from that to using a form, something isn't quite right. I am trying to get the same table to print out to a div area, and simply can't get it at the moment. I am sure it is just my rookie eyes, but I don't see where I am wrong on this one....

thanks for taking the time to help a pleb.

The html -

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
    <title>Loan Amortization</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="LoanAmortization.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Loan Amortization</h1>


    <fieldset>
        <legend>Inputs</legend>
        <form>
            Principal: <input type="text" id="principalInput" /><br />
            Interest:  <input type="text" id="interestInput" /><br />
            Terms:     <select id="termsInput">     

                    <option>12 months</option>
                    <option>24 months</option>
                    <option>36 months</option>
                    <option>48 months</option>
                    <option>60 months</option>
            </select> <br />
            <input type="button" id="myButton" value="Click this!" 
            onclick="amort('principalInput','interestInput','termsInput', 
            'myDiv')" />
        </form>
    </fieldset>


    <fieldset>
        <legend>Outputs</legend>

    <div id="myDiv">


    </div>  
    </fieldset>

</body>
```

the JS -

```
    function amort(principalInput, interestInput, termsInput)
{
    total = parseInt(document.getElementById(principalInput).value);
    var monthlyRate = parseFloat
    (document.getByElementId(interestInput).value)/12;
    var payment = total * (monthlyRate/(1-Math.pow(
        1+monthlyRate, -terms)));

    var result = "Loan amount: $" + principalInput.toFixed(2) +  "<br />" + 
        "Interest rate: " + (interestInput*100).toFixed(2) +  "%<br />" +
        "Number of months: " + termsInput + "<br />" +
        "Monthly payment: $" + payment.toFixed(2) + "<br />" +
        "Total paid: $" + (payment * terms).toFixed(2) + "<br /><br />";

    result += "<table border='1'><tr><th>Month</th><th>Balance</th>" + 
        "<th>Interest</th><th>Principal</th>";

    // insert your code here
    var i = 1;

    var interestPaid = (total * monthlyRate);
    var principalPaid = payment - interestPaid;

    while(i <= terms){
        result+= "<tr><td>" + i + "</td>";
        result+= "<td>" + total.toFixed(2) + "</td>";
        result+= "<td>" + interestPaid.toFixed(2) + "</td>";
        result+= "<td>" + principalPaid.toFixed(2)  + "</td>";
        result+= "</tr>";
        total = total - principalPaid;
        interestPaid = total * monthlyRate;
        principalPaid = payment - interestPaid;
        i++;
    }

    result += "</table>";
    document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = result;
}
```

Comment: The terms variable doesn't exists

Answer (score 0):

First, you're calling your `amort` function with four arguments:

```
onclick="amort('principalInput','interestInput','termsInput','myDiv')"
```

But it's only defined to accept three:

```
function amort(principalInput, interestInput, termsInput)
```

Add the fourth argument to the function definition, then use that in the function instead of hard coding the output div name.

Next, `terms` is not defined before you use it.  You need to add a line where your parse it from the form input.  You'll want to add `value` attributes to the `option` tags in your HTML form so you can read in a number of terms.  See the MDN page on [`<select>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) for an example of how that syntax should look.

You're also calling `principalInput.toFixed(2)` when `principalInput` isn't a number.  You read a value from that field earlier in your code. I think you mean to use that instead.

Comment: I don't understand if you are just pointing that the amount of arguments is incorrect, or if that will throw an error (because it wont). Maybe it's just me.

Comment: @NicoSantangelo Just pointing it out. There are multiple problems in the HTML and JavaScript.

Comment: Ah, allright. To add there (not really an error), `total` seems to be a leaked global.